# gb4e: Highlighting examples

Tags: highlighting, gb4e

In a presentation of a colleague I saw that his examples were displayed in a filled grey square (he used powerpoint). This impressed me, because it highlighted the examples in a subtle and modest way. Now, I would like to know if anyone is able to change the `\begin{exe}-\ex-\end{exe}`-environment in such a way?

**Note**: I suppose that there is a local way to solve the problem and probably I would be able to do so myself. However, I am looking for a global solution.

Comment: You mean a filled grey square or a contour like a box?

Comment: I mean a filled grey square (I added this point in the question)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `mdframed` package to enhance the `exe` enviornment via e.g.

```
\surroundwithmdframed[backgroundcolor=gray!20]{exe}
```

There are many options and styles that may be applied, see the `mdframed` documentation.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,mdframed,gb4e}

\surroundwithmdframed[backgroundcolor=gray!20]{exe}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
  \ex\label{here} Here is one.
  \ex[*]{Here another is.}
  \ex Here are some with judgements.
  \begin{xlist}
    \ex[]{A grammatical sentence am I.}
    \ex[*]{An ungrammatical sentence is you.}
    \ex[??]{A dubious sentence is she.}
    \ex
    \begin{xlist}
      \ex[**]{Need one a second embedding?}
      \ex[\%]{sometime.}
    \end{xlist}
    \ex Dare to judge me!
  \end{xlist}
  \ex This concludes our demonstration.
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I try to compile it, it does not work. There is no output at all. I use OS X 10.6.6 and TexShop. Do you have an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: What version of the files do you have?  Add `\listfiles` to your source and look at the information in the log file.

Comment: In my log file I found this "</usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb><". In the console I found this: "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)". Is that an appropriate answer to your question?

Comment: No it is not the same information.  That is just fonts being loaded and the format version.  My compliation is on a texlive 2015 with mdframed version 2013/07/01 1.9b